# How to preview values of dynamically generated fields with jquery

Tags: php, jquery

I have a form on my website where users fill an input field and selects from a drop down. For more options, a button is provided to generate more fields dynamically for users. That works fine.

Now, I’m trying to implement a functionality that previews the orders made by users (in a table format) immediately the user finish filling the orders field and the name field receives focus but I can’t seems to get it done. Any assistance will be appreciated please.

Here is what I’ve tried so far:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="" id="order_form">
    <fieldset class="orders_det">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="prod_type">Type</label>
            <select name="prod_type[]" class="form-control prod">
                <option value="">-- Select Products --</option>
                <option value="prod1">Prod1</option>
                <option value="prod2">Prod2</option>
                <option value="prod3">Prod3</option>
            </select>
        </div>                      
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="quant" >
            <input type="text" class="form-control quant" name="quant[]">
        </label>
        <div>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="more_btn">Add More Orders + </button>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="name" class="col-md-2 control-label">Name</label>
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <input type="text" class="form-control name" name="name">
        </div>
    </div>                      
    <div class="form-group">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" name="order_submit" id="order_submit">Submit Order</button>
    </div>
</form>
<div class="orders_preview"></div>
```

My jquery:

```
$("form input.name").on("focus", function(e){
    var prod = $("form select[name='prod_type[]']").map(function(){
                return $(this).val(); 
                }).get();
    var quant = $("form input[name='quant[]']").map(function(){
                return ($(this).val()); 
                }).get();
    var table = '';
        table = '<table>';
        table = '<thead>';
        table = '<tr>';
        table = '<th>Product</th>';
        table = '<th>Quantity</th>';
        table = '</tr>';
        table = '</thead>';
        table = '<tbody>';
        table = '<tr>';
        table = '<td>'+prod+'</td>';
        table = '<td>'+quant+'</td>';
        table = '</tr>';
        table = '</tbody>';
        table = '</table>';
    $(".orders_preview").append(table);
 });
```

Comment: I think you mean `table +=` instead of `table =`

Comment: After you first declare `table` you need to use `+=` to add each successive line or all you will get is the last line.

Comment: Thanks @Mike, yogen & Jay, I've corrected that.But that hasn't fixed the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will modify your jquery slightly, changing the event handler to 'on change' instead of 'on focus'. Also, just before the opening tr tag, i will loop through your var prod values, like so;

```
$("form").on("change", function(e) { //to generate a preview table
    var prod = $("form select[name='prod_type[]']")
    var quant = $("form input[name='quant[]']")
    var table = '';
    table += '<table>';
    table += '<thead>';
    table += '<tr>';
    table += '<th>Product</th>';
    table += '<th>Quantity</th>';
    table += '</tr>';
    table += '</thead>';
    table += '<tbody>';
    prod.each(function(i) {
      table += '<tr>';
      table += '<td>' + $(this).val() + '</td>';
      table += '<td>' + quant.eq(i).val() + '</td>';
      table += '</tr>';
    })
    table += '</tbody>';
    table += '</table>';
    $(".orders_preview").html(table);
  });
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `+=` (concatenate each data to the variable)like below:-

```
table += '<table>';
table += '<thead>';...... so on for others
```

***Working example:-***

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('form button#more_btn').on("click", function(e) {//to generate dynamic fields
    e.preventDefault();
    var moreOrders = '';
    moreOrders += '<div class="new_order">';
    moreOrders += '<div class="form-group">';
    moreOrders += '<label for="prod_type">Type</label>';
    moreOrders += '<select name="prod_type[]" class="form-control prod">';
    moreOrders += '<option value="">-- Select Products --</option>';
    moreOrders += '<option value="prod1">Prod1</option>';
    moreOrders += '<option value="prod2">Prod2</option>';
    moreOrders += '<option value="prod3">Prod3</option>';
    moreOrders += '</select>';
    moreOrders += '</div> ';
    moreOrders += '<div class="form-group">';
    moreOrders += '<label for="quant" class="control-label col-md-2" >Quantity</label>';
    moreOrders += '<div class="form-control col-md-6">';
    moreOrders += '<input type="text" class="form-control quant" name="quant[]">';
    moreOrders += '</div>';
    moreOrders += '<div>';
    moreOrders += '</div><br />';
    $('.more_orders').append(moreOrders);
  });

  $("form input.name").on("focus", function(e) {//to generate a preview table
    var prododuct = $("form select[name='prod_type[]']");
    var quantity = $("form input[name='quant[]']");
    var table = '';
    table += '<table>';
    table += '<thead>';
    table += '<tr>';
    table += '<th>Product</th>';
    table += '<th>Quantity</th>';
    table += '</tr>';
    table += '</thead>';
    table += '<tbody>';
    table += '<tr>';
    prododuct.each(function(i) {
      table += '<tr>';
      table += '<td>' + $(this).val() + '</td>';
      table += '<td>' + quantity.eq(i).val() + '</td>';
      table += '</tr>';
    })
    table += '</tr>';
    table += '</tbody>';
    table += '</table>';
    $(".orders_preview").append(table);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="" id="order_form">
  <fieldset class="orders_det">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="prod_type">Type</label>
        <select name="prod_type[]" class="form-control prod">
            <option value="">-- Select Products --</option>
            <option value="prod1">Prod1</option>
            <option value="prod2">Prod2</option>
            <option value="prod3">Prod3</option>
        </select>
    </div>                      
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="quant" class="control-label col-md-2" >Quantity</label>
        <div class="form-control col-md-6">
          <input type="text" class="form-control quant" name="quant[]">
        </div>
      <div>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="more_btn">Add More Orders + </button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="more_orders">
    </div>
  </fieldset>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="name" class="col-md-2 control-label">Name</label>
      <div class="col-md-8">
        <input type="text" class="form-control name" name="name">
      </div>
  </div>                      
  <div class="form-group">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" name="order_submit" id="order_submit">Submit Order</button>
  </div>
</form>
<div class="orders_preview"></div>
```

***jsFiddle working link:-*** https://jsfiddle.net/8jmz4w14/

Comment: thanks i've corrected the concatenation.I'm still not getting the preview

Comment: thanks for your assistance. Here's the fiddle to demonstrate (https://jsfiddle.net/banklan2010/dgc02hxL/)

Comment: @Flexi  check my edited "Working example" section or jsFiddle link. It's working now in your desired way.Thanks

Comment: Thanks @Alive & I so much appreciate your assistance.The accepted answer came long before urs and so had been accepted b4 I got yours, even though yours was more detailed.However, I will ask the new question on a new thread.

Answer (score 1):

By itself `=` does not concatenate, so you need to use `+=` to realize the full table:

```
var table = '';
    table += '<table>';
    table += '<thead>';
    table += '<tr>';
    table += '<th>Product</th>';
    table += '<th>Quantity</th>';
    table += '</tr>';
    table += '</thead>';
    table += '<tbody>';
    table += '<tr>';
    table += '<td>'+prod+'</td>';
    table += '<td>'+quant+'</td>';
    table += '</tr>';
    table += '</tbody>';
    table += '</table>';
```

Comment: that has been corrected. The real issue remains howe've.

Comment: ***[Your code works](https://jsfiddle.net/wL1qj367/)*** for me once this correction is made. Perhaps it just doesn't work as you expect.

Comment: Thanks @ Jay.What I want is each of the dynamic field filled to be displayed on a row of the table.if the user clicks the More button 5 times and fill the fields, then I should have 5 rows on the table excluding the table head.

Comment: Ah - so the first problem has been solved and now you need the logic to add the rows to the table as you desire. That is another question entirely.

Comment: @Jay..exactly what I wanted...the logic to add rows to the table.Please assist.

Comment: @Jay..Here's the fiddle to demonstrate (https://jsfiddle.net/banklan2010/dgc02hxL/)